# Convert data frame to json in R

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I have a data frame **df** that I'd like to convert to json format:

```
df <- data.frame(`ArtId` = rep(c(50,70),each=4), 
  `Year` = rep(1990:1993,times=2), 
  `IndexBV` = c(132,94,83,101,100,100,67,133), 
  `SE` = c(20,15,12,13,NA,NA,NA,NA))

ArtId Year IndexBV SE
50    1990 132     20
50    1991  94     15
50    1992  83     12
50    1993 101     13
70    1990 100     NA
70    1991 110     NA
70    1992  67     NA
70    1993 133     NA
```

The data frame contains index-values (IndexBV) and their standard errors (SE) for two different species (ArtId 50 and 70) for the years 1990-1993.

When I do:

```
cat(jsonlite::toJSON(df, pretty=T))
```

I get this (only the first two elements are shown):

```
[
  {
    "ArtId": 50,
    "Year": 1990,
    "IndexBV": 132,
    "SE": 20
  },
  {
    "ArtId": 50,
    "Year": 1991,
    "IndexBV": 94,
    "SE": 15
  },
...
```

But what I need as **desired.res** is a structure that looks as follows when printed with `cat(jsonlite::toJSON(desired.res, pretty=T))`:

```
{
    "Year":["1990","1991","1992","1993"],
    "ArtId": {
        "50":[
            {"IndexBV": 132, "SE": 20},
            {"IndexBV": 94, "SE": 15},
            {"IndexBV": 83, "SE": 12},
            {"IndexBV": 101, "SE": 13}
        ],
        "70":[
            {"IndexBV": 100, "SE": NA},
            {"IndexBV": 110, "SE": NA},
            {"IndexBV": 67, "SE": NA,
            {"IndexBV": 133, "SE": NA}
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I convert **df** to **desired.res**? 
I think the problem is about reshaping **df** into a nested list to take into account its nested structure.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Nicolas! 
«... but the resulting output is far from what I need» — Well, what **do** you need? :-)

Comment: Think he wants to reshape from long to wide format, with a group column that takes values ("SE", "IndexBV"). It's a good idea to learn a method for moving between long and wide format e.g. for dplyr, have a look at https://uc-r.github.io/tidyr and in particular, the `spread` function

Comment: Hi Roman, I slightly edited the post to be more clear. What I need as a result is the json-like structure *{
    "Year":["1990","1991","1992","1993"],
    "ArtId": { ...*

Comment: That's an odd structure to have as an output. There would be no native way of tying 1990 in Year to the values under ArtId, unless I'm mistaken? Is there code that requires it in this format, or is it just for displaying results?

Comment: Thank you Jonny for the link. Regarding the structure: Our IT-guy asked me to send him the data in a json-file with exactly that format, for displaying it graphically on the homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give a very specific solution, but to generalise will take more work, as its a strange format to me. Try this out, and adapt to make more robust accordingly e.g. the year going from length 8 to length 4.

```
# I find data.table easier
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

# manually can do it, find levels of L, split data and name
L <- unique(df$ArtId)
ArtList <- lapply(L, function(x){
  x.dt <- dt[ArtId == x, .(IndexBV, SE)]
  x.dt
})
names(ArtList) <- L

# combine in to one list
X <- list(Year=unique(dt$Year),
          ArtId = ArtList)

# convert to Json, need either "null" or "string" for na, else dropped
jsonlite::toJSON(X, pretty = TRUE, na="null")
```

Comment: Thank you for this perfectly fitting solution!